# Is WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() necessary for WCF services?

Tags: wcf, impersonation

I am using a windows identity impersonation on a WCF service. Is it necessary to call identity.Impersonate() each time when I need impersonation, or can WCF do it for me? If it can, then what configuration should I specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this in the client configuration using `allowedImpoersonationLevel` of the `windows` element:

```
<windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Identification/Impersonation/Delegation/Anonymous/None"
    allowNtlm="Boolean"/>
```

This page explains more and shows you where this element fits in the config file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731356(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not clear for me yet. Should I add this to client or server web.config file? I can't start the service when I add it to server.

Comment: This is client-side setting. The link I included shows where in the config tree it should go. Here is some more info on Impersonation in WCF http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx

Comment: Also, one the service side, you should mark all service operations that require impersonation with this attribute `[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]`  This page, provide a How-To on WCF impersonation, but the client is implemented in code, rather than config. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751513.aspx